# Prevent SVG viewbox from changing the svg height

Tags: svg

I have an SVG containing random circles with centers from 0,0 to 1000,1000

The SVG should be displayed using the maximum available space in the page layout which works using flexbox.

The problem is as soon as I specify a viewbox height greater than the available height the SVG starts to ignore the height settings and just expands further down, breaking my layout.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" style="background: silver">
    @foreach (var circle in Circles)
    {
        <circle cx="@circle.Item1" cy="@circle.Item2" r="@circle.Item3" fill="@circle.Item4" />
    }
</svg>
```

I want to use the SVG viewbox to zoom and pan around the image like google maps.

Comment: do you want to preserve the aspect ratio. of the SVG?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes.

Comment: Is preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" what you're looking for then?

Comment: @RobertLongson That doesn't do anything as far as I can tell. But I've since figured out an alternative that looks promising: I've dropped the viewBox and am using a g element with a transform attribute instead.

Comment: Can you add a more detailed explanation and example in your question. It is really hard to reproduce now that you only show the code for a more or less standard SVG element. What does the context look like?